# R: MTP in multtest creates different estimates from glm for test="lm.YvsXZ"

Tags: r, multiple-regression, bootstrap, multiple-comparisons

I apologize if I am completely missing something fundamental about what I am trying to do here.

I am trying to use MTP to estimate adjusted p-values for a much more complex regression, and I keep getting parameter estimates that differ wildly from those that I get from glm.

To demonstrate my thinking, here is an example using the mtcars data:

`library(multtest)
data(mtcars)`

`g <- glm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + vs, data=mtcars)
summary(g)`

`mtcars$Intercept <- 1
m <- MTP(X=t(mtcars[c("Intercept","cyl","disp","hp","vs")]),
    Y=mtcars["mpg"],test="lm.YvsXZ", robust=FALSE, typeone="fwer",
    method="sd.maxT", keep.nulldist=FALSE, B=2000)
md <- as.data.frame(cbind(m@estimate, m@statistic, m@rawp, m@adjp))
names(md) <- c("Estimate","t-value","Raw p","Adj p")
md`

As you can see, the estimates and their t-values are very different. This carries over if you do not add the Intercept term to the MTP call (which I am not sure about).

I'm sure that I am not understanding something fundamental about what's going on here, but I am just learning about R and MTP/multtest. I am assuming that bootstrapping would not change the estimates SO much, but maybe I am wrong?

Thanks for any help that you can give.

Answer (score 0):

I talked with the very helpful Dr. Pollard, and I was confused about 2 points:
   1) Using "lm.YvsXZ" requires that *something* be in the Z matrix as well as the X matrix, and
   2) MTP was designed to adjust one predictor at a time. If you have more than one predictor that needs adjustment put them, one at a time and serially, in X, and the rest in Z for as many rounds as you have predictors.

So, I need to use multcomp.